# Fix for sprites with msDropDown jQuery in IE7/8?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins, css-sprites

I am using the [msDropDown jQuery plugin](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/jquery-image-dropdown) to add images to dropdowns on my site, using their Sprited option. Everything works great in all tested versions of Chrome, Firefox, and IE9. Stepping back to IE7 or IE8, however, breaks things. It still *almost* works, in that all of the selection elements get the right images. However, the image in the "title" option never changes (e.g. the one that is displayed when you do **not** have the dropdown open). It always displays the topmost sprite.

I'll note that this problem appears to be present on [the author's css-version demo](http://www.marghoobsuleman.com/mywork/jcomponents/image-dropdown/samples/cssSprite.html). What is going wrong to stop earlier versions from IE from working? How can it be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments thread on the author's site, another user and I were going back and forth and it seems that he has found the problem. It isn't wholely solved, but it should lead to some solutions.

He [posted details about what is going on](https://github.com/marghoobsuleman/ms-Dropdown/issues/3) but basically it comes down to an inconsistency in how different versions of IE behave where it comes to interpretting `background-position: Xpx Ypx;` vs `background-position-x: Xpx; background-position-y: Ypx;`

Initially, I thought that adding some external JS to handle this difference should solve the issue. That failed, however, because all of the events that I could attach to were executed somewhere in the middle of the MS DropDown plugin execution.

Instead, I made direct modification to the plugin. I de-minified, then made my changes, then re-minified. Testing confirms that everything is working properly now. I have forked the [MS DropDown repo on gitHub](https://github.com/marghoobsuleman/ms-Dropdown) and updated with [my new version](https://github.com/jgb146/ms-Dropdown).

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this issue before and often has to do with `position: relative;` mucking things up in IE. That being said, I didn't see any of that in the author example but see the issue.

Here is all I could find on it http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-173790.html but isn't much help other than confirms the issues I've seen.

The only other thing that I notice is that the example doesn't utilize the `title="
relative/image.loc"` but the documentation for the plugin references it being used.

Maybe check that and try to add the title attribute to see if that works. Just shooting ideas out since it is IE.

When debugging IE, I usually resort to Firebug Lite (http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) to give a little bit of help where possible. Might help you here.

Not much help from me but IE is frustrating so I figure I'd at least try.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help :) A couple questions: 

`position: relative;` breaks sprites in IE7/8? Really? I've never seen that happen.

Also, unless I'm mistaken, the documentation's reference to `title="relative/image.loc"` refers to using the non-sprite version of this plugin, which doesn't fit my needs.

Comment: I've had relative break it once and ended up giving up on sprites. There may very well have been another reason but I usually end up fixing IE with the whack-a-mole approach so I'm hardly an expert on it. I'll see if I can load the example up over here and see if I get anywhere.

Comment: No need to load it and spend time -- someone else on the author's site managed to track it down. And I agree completely with the whack-a-mole approach to IE. It deserves all the whacks it can get and then some.

Comment: I figured out the issue, though it sounds like you may have too. It doesn't add in the background-position values for the sprite on IE for some reason. Once I manually added that in, the sprites load.